# Idiom/expression that means "to hastily make"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there any idiom/expression for that?

Example sentence:

> Their dinner today was the curry rice she had __ after work.

Comment: what about "knocked up"? How formal?

Comment: @marcellothearcane it can be informal.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I thought to "knock up" meant to make someone pregnant.

Comment: yeah, that as well. but it can also mean to hastily make (probably a britishism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [rustle up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rustle-up-something): to make, find or prepare something quickly.

> Their dinner today was the curry rice she had rustled up after work

Or [throw together](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/throw-together): to make something quickly because you do not have much time.

> Their dinner today was the curry rice she had thrown together after work

Or [cobble together](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cobble-together): to produce something roughly or quickly. (This has the sense that dinner was assembled from a set of ingredients that might not have been ideal.)

> Their dinner today was the curry rice she had cobbled together after work.

Comment: *Together* is the operative word. You can use many different “quick” motion verbs with it to indicate “hastily made”, including *throw*, *toss*, *cobble*, *slap*, *bodge*, *botch*, *tack*, *stick*, *sling*, and *fling*. Another synonym that comes to mind is *jury-rig* / *jerry-rig*; and for adjectives, there are also *slapdash*, *slipshod*, and *haphazard* (e.g. *a slapdash job* or *haphazardly assembled*).

Answer (score 2):

How about to concoct ? sometimes it's used in a way to describe a hurried creation, without much prior thought or planning.

"I concocted a meal of pasta and chicken with cheese on top for my unexpected dinner guests tonight."

p.s. how do you make a sentence appear with a yellow background ? ^^